# Anyone tried FadeInImage.assetNetwork to load asset placeholder and asset image?

Tags: flutter

Can someone please confirm if they have a working version of "FadeInImage.assetNetwork" in live web server that actually loads Asset placeholder and Asset Image?

I am able to test this in localhost but when i move it to live server then it only loads the placeholder and not the actual image. I have tried the fadeInDuration and fadeInCurve but it only loads the placeholder.

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
            placeholder: 'assets/img/progress.gif',
            // fadeInDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            // fadeInCurve: Curves.easeIn,
            image: "assets/img/" + painting.imageUrl[0].toString(),
          )
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests `assetNetwork` , `FadeInImage` accepts only an image url to its `image` parameter to load an image from network. It can't be used to load an Image from assets.